# if else Ajax success restapi Sharepoint Online

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Im trying to show a custom 'No new uploads' message when the rest api returns no entries on Success event. The code below works perfect when rows are returned on Success event and shows blank on 0 entries.

I tried implementing if else statement with no luck. Kindly assist.

```
$(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        today = moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var currentDate = today+'T00:00:00.000Z';
        var requestUri = "@SPO_SITE@/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LIST_NAME')/items?$top=20000&$select=DistrDate,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter= DistrDate ge datetime'" +currentDate+ "'";
           $.ajax({
              url: requestUri,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: onSuccess,
});
  function onSuccess(data) {
     var objItems = data.d.results;
     var tableContent = '<table id="mbrTable" style="width:100%"><caption class="text-info">Report</caption>';
     for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
         tableContent += '<tr>';
         tableContent += '<td>' + moment(objItems[i].DistrDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") + " - " + "<a target='_blank' href=" + objItems[i].EncodedAbsUrl + ">" + "View" + "</a>" + '</td>';
         tableContent += '</tr>';
 }
   document.getElementById("mbrTable").innerHTML = (tableContent);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following fixed the issue.

```
$(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        today = moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var currentDate = today+'T00:00:00.000Z';
        var requestUri = "@SPO_SITE@/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LIST_NAME')/items?$top=20000&$select=DistrDate,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter= DistrDate ge datetime'" +currentDate+ "'";
           $.ajax({
              url: requestUri,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: onSuccess,
});
  function onSuccess(data) {
    var objItems = data.d.results;
    if (objItems.length == 0) {
    var tableContent = '<table id="mbrTable" style="width:100%"><caption class="text-info">Report</caption><tr><td>No new uploads</td></tr>';
    }
    else {
    var tableContent = '<table id="mbrTable" style="width:100%"><caption class="text-info">Report</caption>';
    for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
         tableContent += '<tr>';
         tableContent += '<td>' + moment(objItems[i].DistrDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") + " - " + "<a target='_blank' href=" + objItems[i].EncodedAbsUrl + ">" + "View" + "</a>" + '</td>';
         tableContent += '</tr>';
        }
    }
   document.getElementById("mbrTable").innerHTML = (tableContent);
   }
});
```